# How to hide OutputMessages window in SALOME ParaViS? Some ideas in question body

Tags: pyqt, pyqt5, paraview

I want to hide Output Messages window in SALOME v.8.3.0. Now I try to get access to `QWidget` "OutputWindow" with inner SALOME console.

One way which I want to do it is to find a slot which connects with `triggered()` signal of `Tools->Output Window` main menu action.
But I don't know how to capture slot if I emit my signal. Also, I couldn't find the slot implementation in the source code of ParaViS module.

Maybe you know how to capture slot or how to find which QObjects are spawned in this slot?

Or you know the simple way to hide this annoying window?...

[image: Here is the view of SALOME window with OutputMessageWindow]

Comment: Which version of ParaView is it based on?

Comment: @MathieuWestphal 5.1.2 64bit

Comment: This has been fixed since ParaView 5.4, where this window can be docked. I'm not familiar with Salome release schedule though.

Comment: @MathieuWestphal yes, I know it. Unfortunately, I should use 5.1.2 Paraview version because SALOME version is fixed(( may be you now how to change some python modules in Paraview for success?...

Comment: should be doable with pyQt

Comment: @MathieuWestphal but I couldn't find it in pyQt( I try to find receivers of the triggered signal of the button "Output Window" in Tools menu, but SALOME say that protected functions which are not created in Python could not be used...

Comment: you should be able to find the window in hide it in pyQt

Comment: @MathieuWestphal I can get access to MainWindow by sgPyQt.getDesktop() command. OutputMessages window is not a child of MainWindow. Maybe I should find an application in pyQt but I can't see any command to get it((